When is the leaf of a foliation on the quotient by a properly discontinuous free group action isomorphic to a leaf on the total space?
Let $\tilde M$ be a manifold and $G$ a discrete group acting freely and properly discontinuously on $\tilde M$. Let $M:= M/G$ and $p: \tilde M \rightarrow M$ is the projection; then $p$ is a covering space. Suppose $\tilde D$ is an involutive distribution on $\tilde M$ and $D$ is an involutive distribution on $M$ such that $p_*(\tilde D) = D$.
Let $L$ be a leaf of the foliation associated to $D$ on $M$ (by "leaf" I mean maximal connected submanifold tangent to a distribution).
I am trying to answer the questions: under which conditions on $\tilde D$ is it true that the leaf $L$ is isomorphic to a leaf of the foliation $\tilde D$ and why?
What I've managed to prove using elementary means and the maximality of $L$ is that in all cases it's true that for any point $ \tilde x \in p^{-1}(L)$, the leaft $\tilde L$ passing through that point is entirely contained in $p^{-1}(L)$ and in fact $G \tilde L \subset p^{-1}(L)$.
Now, I suspect that more is true:

Lemma: exists a leaf $\tilde L$ such that $p^{-1}(L) = G\tilde L$ and moreover $L$ is isomorphic to a connected component of $G \tilde L$.

I am unsure if more conditions are required for such a result.
I'm particularly interested in an additional condition:

(C) for any leaf $\tilde L$ of $\tilde D$ and any $g \in G$, either $g \tilde L \cap \tilde L = \emptyset$ or $g = \textrm{id}_G$

Thus, if the Lemma holds and we assume condition (C), we'd have that indeed $L$ must be isomorphic to a leaf of $\tilde D$.
I'm unsure if we need condition (C) for the lemma itself to hold or if we need some more relaxed condition. In either case, I don't know how to make progress on the Lemma even if I assume condition (C).
So my question is: when is the Lemma true, and why is it true in that case?
